# Periodic sync in Android

Tags: android, listview

In my application, I have a tabactivity where the first tab displays a listview. This listview contains data from server. This data keeps changing and needs to be refreshed after specified time. I have another class called Settings where I have a sliderbar. Depending on the value of seekbar, I should set it as the time after which this listview should get refreshed automatically(i.e make http req and get response and display). Problem is, when I set value in Settings inside TimerTask class,I cannot reflect it in my listview. If I call the function in Settings, setListAdapter is giving error as it cannot be called in another class and should be called inside onCreate itself. My timertask class is a normal java class. Please help as to how do I implement periodic sync such that, if I set time as 15secs, every 15secs the listview should get refreshed.

```
            array_spinner=new String[9];
    array_spinner[0]="Select your timer";
    array_spinner[1]="15-sec";
    array_spinner[2]="30-sec";
    array_spinner[3]="1-min";
    array_spinner[4]="2-min";
    array_spinner[5]="5-min";
    array_spinner[6]="7-min";
    array_spinner[7]="10-min";
    array_spinner[8]="15-min";
```

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

```
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(isRunning())
            {
                timer.cancel();
                StartTimer();
            }
            else
                StartTimer();
        }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    });
```

public class TimerTick extends TimerTask 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
           //INTENT TO FETCH DEVICES...SHould pass value chosen in array_spinner
                 }
            }